# how to write test class for aggregate function?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have written the test class for my apex class. The test class is not covered inside the aggregate functions. Please help me out !

```
My apex class:
public with sharing class Rfleet_DashboardcurrentYear{
public decimal Dvol{get;set;}
public decimal dElTarSum{get;set;}
public decimal tArRatioSum{get;set;}
public decimal dElComSum{get;set;}
public decimal cOmRatioSum{get;set;}
public decimal iKamForcastSum{get;set;}
public String mOnthName{get;set;}
public decimal cUrntMonth{get;set;}
public decimal cOunForcastSum{get;set;}
public decimal cOunForCastRatio{get;set;} 
public decimal cUrntYear{get;set;}
public String str{get;set;}
public String s{get;set;}
public String selectedval{get;set;}
public decimal iKamForcastRatio{get;set;} 
public decimal iKamForcastRatioIn;
public decimal cOunForCastRatioIn;
public decimal maxvalue{get;set;} 
public Rfleet_DashboardcurrentYear(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
//Global deliveries Realized
    List<AggregateResult> tAr=[select SUM(Countries_delivered_volume__c) from IKAM_Data__c where Current_month__c=this_year group by CALENDAR_YEAR(Current_month__c)];
    for (AggregateResult ar : tAr)  {
    Dvol=(decimal)ar.get('expr0');
     }
// Annual global deliveries target   
    AggregateResult[] tArRatio=[select SUM(Target_ratio__c) from IKAM_Data__c where Current_month__c=this_year group by CALENDAR_YEAR(Current_month__c)];
    for (AggregateResult ar : tArRatio)  {
    Decimal tArRatioSumIn=(decimal) ar.get('expr0');
    tArRatioSum=tArRatioSumIn.setScale(0,System.Roundingmode.HALF_UP); 
    }

    AggregateResult[] dElTar=[select SUM(Annual_deliveries_target__c) from IKAM_Data__c where Current_month__c=this_year group by CALENDAR_YEAR(Current_month__c)];
    for (AggregateResult ar : dElTar)  {
    dElTarSum=(decimal) ar.get('expr0');
    //system.debug('<<<<<<<a value'+dElTarSum);
    }
//Annual global deliveries Commitment
    AggregateResult[] cOmRatio=[select SUM(Commitment_Ratio__c) from IKAM_Data__c where Current_month__c=this_year group by CALENDAR_YEAR(Current_month__c)];
    for (AggregateResult ar : cOmRatio)  {
    Decimal cOmRatioSumIn=(decimal) ar.get('expr0');
    //system.debug('<<<<<<<a value'+cOmRatioSumIn);
    if(cOmRatioSumIn!=null)
    cOmRatioSum=cOmRatioSumIn.setScale(0,System.Roundingmode.HALF_UP); 
    }


    AggregateResult[] dElCom=[select SUM(Annual_global_deliveries_commitment__c) from IKAM_Data__c where Current_month__c=this_year group by CALENDAR_YEAR(Current_month__c)];
    for (AggregateResult ar : dElCom)  {
    dElComSum=(decimal) ar.get('expr0');
    //system.debug('<<<<<<<a value'+dElComSum);
    }
//Country Forecast

    AggregateResult[] cOunForcast=[select SUM(Countries_forecast__c) from IKAM_Data__c where Current_month__c=this_year group by CALENDAR_YEAR(Current_month__c)];
    if(cOunForcast.size()>0)
    {
    for (AggregateResult ar : cOunForcast)  {
    cOunForcastSum=(decimal) ar.get('expr0');
    //system.debug('<<<<<<<a value'+cOunForcastSum);
    }
    }

    if(cOunForcastSum!=null)
    {
    cOunForCastRatioIn=(Dvol/cOunForcastSum)*100;
    cOunForCastRatio=cOunForCastRatioIn.setScale(0,System.Roundingmode.HALF_UP); 
    }

//Current year

    AggregateResult[] cUrntYr=[select CALENDAR_YEAR(Current_month__c) from IKAM_Data__c where Current_month__c=this_year group by CALENDAR_YEAR(Current_month__c)];
    for (AggregateResult ar : cUrntYr)  {
    cUrntYear=(Integer) ar.get('expr0');
    //system.debug('<<<<<<<a value'+cUrntYear);
    }
    str=String.valueof(cUrntYear);

//Current month
    AggregateResult[] cUrntMon=[select CALENDAR_MONTH(Current_month__c) from IKAM_Data__c where Current_month__c=this_year group by CALENDAR_MONTH(Current_month__c) order by CALENDAR_MONTH(Current_month__c) desc limit 1];
    for (AggregateResult ar : cUrntMon)  {
    cUrntMonth=(Integer) ar.get('expr0');
    //system.debug('<<<<<<<a value'+cUrntMonth);
    }

If(cUrntMonth==1){mOnthName='January';}
else if(cUrntMonth==2){mOnthName='February';}
else if(cUrntMonth==3){mOnthName='March';}
else if(cUrntMonth==4){mOnthName='April';}
else if(cUrntMonth==5){mOnthName='May';}
else if(cUrntMonth==6){mOnthName='June';}
else if(cUrntMonth==7){mOnthName='July';}
else if(cUrntMonth==8){mOnthName='August';}
else if(cUrntMonth==9){mOnthName='September';}
else if(cUrntMonth==10){mOnthName='October';}
else if(cUrntMonth==11){mOnthName='November';}
else if(cUrntMonth==12){mOnthName='December';}
else{}

    AggregateResult[] iKamForcast=[select SUM(IKAM_forecast__c) from Account where Current_month__c=this_year group by CALENDAR_YEAR(Current_month__c)];
    if(iKamForcast.size()>0)
    {
    for (AggregateResult ar : iKamForcast)  {
    iKamForcastSum=(decimal) ar.get('expr0');
   // system.debug('<<<<<<<a value'+iKamForcastSum);
    }
    }


    if(iKamForcastSum!=null)
    {
    iKamForcastRatioIn=(Dvol/iKamForcastSum)*100;
    iKamForcastRatio=iKamForcastRatioIn.setScale(0,System.Roundingmode.HALF_UP); 
    }

      maxvalue= (dElTarSum>dElComSum&& dElTarSum>cOunForcastSum&& dElTarSum>iKamForcastSum) ? dElTarSum: ((dElComSum>cOunForcastSum && dElComSum>iKamForcastSum) ? dElComSum: ((cOunForcastSum>iKamForcastSum)?cOunForcastSum: iKamForcastSum)) ;  
    }  


}
```

My Test class:

```
@isTest
public class Rfleet_DashboardcurrentYear_Test {    
static testMethod void DashboardcurrentYear(){
test.startTest();
        Id rType =[Select id from RecordType where sObjectType = 'Account' and name='RFLEET-ACC-DCVF-RT'].id;    
        Account acc = new Account(Name='Prabu',Montant__c=5,recordtypeid=rType);
        insert acc;
        system.debug('-------->acc value is ' + acc);
        IKAM_Data__c ikam=new IKAM_Data__c(Annual_deliveries_target__c=45,Annual_global_deliveries_commitment__c=98,IKAM_Year__c=2015,CurrencyIsoCode='INR',Account__c=acc.id);
        insert ikam;

        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(ikam);  
        Rfleet_DashboardcurrentYear accPageCtrl = new Rfleet_DashboardcurrentYear (new ApexPages.StandardController(ikam));     


        accPageCtrl.Dvol=6.8;   
        accPageCtrl.cOmRatioSum=34.5;
        accPageCtrl.cOunForCastRatio=23.3;
        accPageCtrl.cOunForcastSum=67.8;
        accPageCtrl.cUrntMonth=9.0;
        accPageCtrl.cUrntYear=2015.0;
        accPageCtrl.dElComSum=56.8;
        accPageCtrl.dElTarSum=89;     
        accPageCtrl.iKamForcastRatio=8.7;
        accPageCtrl.iKamForcastSum=56.7;
        accPageCtrl.mOnthName='january';
        accPageCtrl.iKamForcastRatioIn=9.8;
        accPageCtrl.cOunForCastRatioIn=6.7;
        accPageCtrl.tArRatioSum=5.6;
        accPageCtrl.selectedval='hjk';
        accPageCtrl.str='gjg';
        accPageCtrl.s='jh';
        test.stopTest();
}
}
```

I have added the screenshot for uncovered lines in my apex class
[image]

Comment: what about the variable this_year? where is this declared? Might be a dumb question.

Comment: This_year is a calendar function and it returns the current year e.g(2015).It is compared with the Current_ month_ c which is formula field contain value as 23-11-2015.So the 2015 from  Current_ month_ c( 23-11-2015) is compared with the This _ year(2015)

Comment: isn't the formula field Current_Month__c is supposed to return 11(in case of 23-11-2015) and which you are comparing against an year(2015)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special to cover the aggregate functions line. Just match your if conditions for example in your test class In this Object `IKAM_Data__c` this field `Current_month__c` is null but in your query you are using this field in if conditions. So fill this field It will give you result and cover your lines. Also If you don't know the exact value what you need to fill then use System Debug. It will help you in solve this problem.